# AWS RDS Postgres error - "no pg_hba.conf entry for host..."

Tags: python, postgresql, amazon-web-services, sqlalchemy, amazon-rds

I have two rds postgres databases. One in eu-west-1 (Ireland) and one in us-east-1 (N. Virginia). The one in eu-west-1 suddenly throws this error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) connection to server at "database-2.<xxx>.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com" (<db ip>), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
connection to server at "database-2.<xxx>.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com" (<db ip>), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "<my ip>", user "postgres", database "postgres", no encryption
```

This is my code:

```
engine_sync = create_engine(
    "postgresql://<user>:<password>:@database-2.<xxx>.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com/postgres")

Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()
session.query(Game).filter_by(name="Alley Cat").first()
```

I didn't make any change, it just started happening.

Comment: Has `<db-ip>` changed?

Comment: @snakecharmerb I don't know what it was before. I successfully connect to it using pgadmin.

Comment: @snakecharmerb Now I can't connect it using pgadmin. I could connect a few minutes ago. Now I get the same error.

Comment: @snakecharmerb Now it works again. I see that the password in the secrets manager has changed (the credentials are managed in secrets manager). Does it make sense that the db password has changed but the password I see in the console, and the one I get from the boto3 api, are different and maybe I get the old one from the cache or that they're just not synchronized?

Comment: I don#t use AWS, so I can't really comment on that. From a Postgres perspective, I wouldn't have thought that the original error message indicated a password problem, but I could be wrong on that.

Comment: I am having the same issue with a serverless postgres RDS in `us-east-1`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with a serverless RDS cluster that used SecretsManager and automatic password rotation.  The problem was resolved by going to the Secrets Manager secret associated with my RDS and clicking "rotate secret immediately" (note: it takes a few minutes for the `Last rotate date` to updated, be patient).

My **guess** about the cause is that AWS secret rotation silently failed to update the RDS, so there was a secrets mismatch and `psycopg2` returns a strange error for a simple bad password.